# why is integral of $\frac{1}{z}$ over $z=2e^{i\theta}$ not equal to zero (for complete contour)?

Tags: complex-analysis

According to Cauchy Goursat theorem integral of $f(z)$ over a closed contour is zero when $f(z)$ is completely analytical in the domain where the contour lies. Since $\frac{1}{z}$ is completely analytical over the curve $r=2e^{i\theta}$, why is $$\int\frac{1}{z} dz$$ not equal to zero?

Comment: The contour cannot encircle any "hole", i.e. domain $U$ that contains this contour must be simply connected. Fucntion $\frac{1}{z}$ is a perfect example why this is a necessary condition.

Answer (score 5):

For Cauchy's integral theorem you need that $f$ is defined on some simply connected domain $U$ which contains the closed contour. For $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ and $|z| = 2$ no such domain exists the loop $|z| = 2$ is not contractible in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, the maximal domain of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood that for the integral of 1/z to be zero over |z|=2 it needs to be completely analytic on as well as inside curve |z|=2.Cauchy Riemann equations must hold while converting the contour integral to a double integral for contour integral to evaluate to zero, otherwise the real and imaginary double integrals become non-zero.